# Copy a struct into a struct which implement an interface

Tags: go

I'm currently trying to copy a struct into another structure which implement an interface. My code is the following:

```
     package main

     import (
         "fmt"
     )

     type intf interface {
         SaySomething(string)
         LaunchTheDevice(origin)
     }

     type destination struct{
         origin
     }

     func (dest *destination) SaySomething(s string) {
         fmt.Println("I'm saying --> ",s)
     }

     func (dest *destination) LaunchTheDevice(theOrigin origin) {
        *dest = theOrigin
     }

     type origin struct{
         name string
         value string
         infos string   
     }

     func main() {
         firstValue:= new(origin)
         firstValue.name = "Nyan"
         firstValue.value = "I'm the only one"
         firstValue.infos = "I'm a cat"

         secondValue := new(destination)
         secondValue.LaunchTheDevice(*firstValue)
     }
```

I want that the function `LaunchTheDevice()` set the values of `destination`. But when I run my code I get this error:

```
cannot use theOrigin (type origin) as type destination in assignment
```

So how can I do this? And why I can't run my code? I don't understand because I can type

```
dest.name = "a value"
dest.value = "another value"
dest.infos = "another value"
```

But `dest=theOrigin` doesn't work while `dest` have the same struct as `theOrigin`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `dest.origin = theOrigin`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field `origin` is an embedded field. The application can set the field using the following code:

```
 func (dest *destination) LaunchTheDevice(theOrigin origin) {
    dest.origin = theOrigin
 }
```

The name of an embedded field is the same as the type name.